# Is it possible to use pdb files in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pdb-files

For debugging purposes it is possible to get the `.pdb` files for all dlls shipped with Windows.

Can the Delphi debugger use these files? I would like to see detailed callstack if the calls are going through windows dlls inside the Delphi IDE stack trace window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to use .pdb files in Delphi. The Delphi debugger only supports debugging with its own proprietary debug files.

Comment: So what kind of symbol tables can you specify in the project options Debugger|Symbol Tables?

Comment: From the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_the_Search_Order_for_Debug_Symbol_Tables): *Delphi does not use external symbol files because the compiler holds the symbols tables in memory*.

Comment: Ok, I used Windbg to see the non Delphi part of the stacktrace.